# How to change code written in async to callback function

Tags: javascript

I wrote code that uses util.promisify and async to read the file and display it on localhost: 3000.

But I want to write this code without using async and promise.

I made the following attempts.
However, console.log ("running 3000") is output, but my server goes into an infinite loop.

How can I run code as planned?

**async code (original)**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

var app = http.createServer(function(req , res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
  getData().then(data => {
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  })

});

app.listen(3000);

async function getData(callback) {
  console.log("running 3000");
  return await readFile('./a.txt');
}
```

**callback code (repack)**

```
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var util = require('util');

    var app = http.createServer(function(req , res){
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
      getData(data =>{
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      })
    });

    app.listen(3000);

const getData = callback =>{
  console.log("running 3000");
  fs.readFile('./a.txt', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      callback(data);
  )};
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use promises, why have you used `util.promisify`?

Comment: You've defined a `callback` argument to your `getData` function … but you never call it!

Comment: Don't completely change your question after people have already posted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use `util.promisify`
- Do **use** your `callback` instead of just defining it
- Do [follow the example in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

Such:

```
// var readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);


const getData = callback =>{
  console.log("running 3000");
  fs.readFile('./a.txt', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      callback(data);
  };
}
```